# I am getting this channel input and output mismatch error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am getting this channel mismacth error **RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 2, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 256, 256] to have 2 channels, but got 1 channels instead**

in_channels = 2 but still i cant understand the cause of error.

Here is the segmentation model

```py
class SegmentationModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super(SegmentationModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(2, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.upconv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.upconv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.upconv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.upconv4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.final_conv = nn.Conv2d(64, 2, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Assuming x is of shape [batch_size, channels, height, width]
        x1 = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x2 = F.relu(self.conv2(x1))
        x3 = F.relu(self.conv3(x2))
        x4 = F.relu(self.conv4(x3))
        x5 = F.relu(self.conv5(x4))
        
        x6 = F.relu(self.upconv1(x5))
        x7 = F.relu(self.upconv2(x6))
        x8 = F.relu(self.upconv3(x7))
        x9 = F.relu(self.upconv4(x8))
        
        output = self.final_conv(x9)
  
        return output
```

Here are the input output shapes:

```
Image shape: torch.Size([2, 256, 256])

Mask shape: torch.Size([2, 256, 256])
Output shape: torch.Size([1, 2, 4096, 4096])

Resized output shape: torch.Size([1, 2, 256, 256])
Resized_Image shape: torch.Size([1, 2, 256, 256])
Resized_Mask shape: torch.Size([1, 2, 256, 256])
```

Error Traceback

```
---------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 51
     47 optimizer.zero_grad()
     50  # Forward pass
---> 51 outputs = model(resized_images)
     53 # Resize the output tensor to match the spatial dimensions of the target tensor
     54 resized_outputs = F.interpolate(outputs, size=(256, 256), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Cell In[16], line 17, in SegmentationModel.forward(self, x)
     15 def forward(self, x):
     16     # Assuming x is of shape [batch_size, channels, height, width]
---> 17     x1 = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
     18     x2 = F.relu(self.conv2(x1))
     19     x3 = F.relu(self.conv3(x2))

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:463, in Conv2d.forward(self, input)
    462 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 463     return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py:459, in Conv2d._conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    455 if self.padding_mode != 'zeros':
    456     return F.conv2d(F.pad(input, self._reversed_padding_repeated_twice, mode=self.padding_mode),
    457                     weight, bias, self.stride,
    458                     _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
--> 459 return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
    460                 self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 2, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 256, 256] to have 2 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

Comment: @kmkurn could you please tell what's wrong here

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Done Please have a look

Comment: @kmkurn or i can share my Kaggle code link with you if that's ok with you